# JPQL selected expression

Tags: jpa-2.0

The construct "SELECT NEW MAP" is allowed in Hibernate HQL but is not allowed in JPA 2.0 JPQL. Is there any circunvention to this limitation? (besides post-processing the result, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly `"SELECT NEW MAP"` does. But looks like the [JPQL Constructor Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor).

It says:

> in the SELECT Clause A constructor may be used in the SELECT list to return one or more Java instances.

It has a sample:

```
SELECT NEW com.company.PublisherInfo(pub.id, pub.revenue, mag.price)
FROM Publisher pub JOIN pub.magazines mag WHERE mag.price > 5.00
```

Which uses `SELECT NEW` with the constructor of `PublisherInfo` class, which is not required to be an entity. But, the fully qualified name is required (i.e. `com.company.PublisherInfo`).